# Python: tkinter doubles tkinter.Entry.insert

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this 'simple' code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime


class Page(tk.Frame):
    
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        # Set up
        super().__init__(root)
        # Labels
        self.labels = {}
        # Buttons
        self.buttons = {}
        # Entries
        self.entries = {}
        
        # Year label
        self.labels["year"] = ttk.Label(self, text="Year")
        self.labels["year"].grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Month label
        self.labels["month"] = ttk.Label(self, text="Month")
        self.labels["month"].grid(row=0, column=1)
        # Day label
        self.labels["day"] = ttk.Label(self, text="Day")
        self.labels["day"].grid(row=0, column=2)
        # Year entry
        self.year = tk.IntVar()
        self.entries["year"] = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.year)
        self.entries["year"].delete(0, "end")
        self.entries["year"].grid(row=1, column=0)
        # Month entry
        self.month = tk.IntVar()
        self.entries["month"] = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.month)
        self.entries["month"].delete(0, "end")
        self.entries["month"].grid(row=1, column=1)
        # Day entry
        self.day = tk.IntVar()
        self.entries["day"] = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.day)
        self.entries["day"].delete(0, "end")
        self.entries["day"].grid(row=1, column=2)
        # Today button
        self.buttons["today"] = ttk.Button(self, text="Today",
            command=lambda:self._f_buttonToday())
        self.buttons["today"].grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="WE")
    
    
    def _f_buttonToday(self):
        
        year, month, day = map(int, datetime.date.today().isoformat().split("-"))
        self.year.set(year)
        self.month.set(month)
        self.day.set(day)
        #self.entries["year"].delete(0, "end")
        self.entries["year"].insert(0, self.year.get())
        self.entries["month"].insert(0, self.month.get())
        self.entries["day"].insert(0, self.day.get())


root = tk.Tk()
page = Page(root)
page.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When you press the button, the text in the entries is updated, but it is doubled:

[image: picture]

I've already checked and the `self.year`, `self.month` and `self.day` variables are right and the button command is executed only once.

How can I solve this? I don't know if it might be related or not, but if I uncomment `self.entries["year"].delete(0, "end")`, I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 592, in get
    return self._tk.getint(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got ""

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\SportsPy\here\test.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    command=lambda:self._f_buttonToday())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\SportsPy\here\test.py", line 56, in _f_buttonToday
    self.entries["year"].insert(0, self.year.get())
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 594, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue:

```
def _f_buttonToday(self):
        
    year, month, day = map(int, datetime.date.today().isoformat().split("-"))
    self.year.set(year)
    self.month.set(month)
    self.day.set(day)
    #self.entries["year"].delete(0, "end")
    self.entries["year"].insert(0, self.year.get())
    self.entries["month"].insert(0, self.month.get())
    self.entries["day"].insert(0, self.day.get())
```

When updating `self.year`, the `self.entries["year"]` content is already updated.

For the `tkinter.Entry.delete` issue, I just moved that lines.

Right function:

```
def _f_buttonToday(self):
        
    year, month, day = map(int, datetime.date.today().isoformat().split("-"))
    self.entries["year"].delete(0, "end")
    self.entries["month"].delete(0, "end")
    self.entries["day"].delete(0, "end")
    self.year.set(year)
    self.month.set(month)
    self.day.set(day)
```

Comment: I have not tested it, but I think that the `self.entries["..."].delete(0, "end")` aren't needed as the `.set` handles everything.